# Nursing process in / for / of a Patient with Diabetes Mellitus

Tags: prepositions

Can you help me with a correct preposition in the name of my final thesis?

> Nursing process **in / for / of** a Patient with Diabetes Mellitus

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Nursing process **for** a patient with diabetes mellitus.

Answer (score 1):

Of the three choices given, "for" is the most appropriate but "Nursing process for a patient with diabetes mellitus" still sounds a little unnatural to me.

I'd suggest **"Process for Nursing a Patient with Diabetes Meliitus"**.